# Fix broken ntfs filesystem from Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, ntfs

My laptop battery ran out while doing some file copy operation to a filesystem. Now things are seemingly OK (at least from the outside) in the filesystem, but when I am trying to do some cleanup operation on the directory where I was writing, it's giving:

```
cannot remove <Directory name>: Directory not empty
```

I think it's due to some broken inodes, when I run `ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sda1`, it says `No bad clusters...OK`

Are there any tools to do the cleanup, how I'd love to see my file system clean and error-free.

Adding the debug messages:

```
sudip@sudip:~$ rm -rf /media/sudip/4024C64A24C64320/sudip/
rm: cannot remove '/media/sudip/4024C64A24C64320/sudip/Android/Sdk/emulator': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/media/sudip/4024C64A24C64320/sudip/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/databinding': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove '/media/sudip/4024C64A24C64320/sudip/androidApps/cutePuppyPics/node_modules/ieee754': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/media/sudip/4024C64A24C64320/sudip/androidApps/cutePuppyPics/node_modules/immediate': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/media/sudip/4024C64A24C64320/sudip/androidApps/cutePuppyPics/node_modules/ipaddr.js': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/media/sudip/4024C64A24C64320/sudip/androidApps/cutePuppyPics/node_modules/is': Directory not empty

sudip@sudip:~$ sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sda1
[sudo] password for sudip: 
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
Going to un-mark the bad clusters ($BadClus)... No bad clusters...OK
NTFS partition /dev/sda1 was processed successfully.
```

Comment: what command did you run exactly to get exactly what error message ? copy paste your command(s) and output directly from terminal to here.

Comment: I suggest listing files `ls -la`  (-a for all files) and you may find a hidden file/folder there.  Hidden folders have a '.' as first character.

Comment: I suggest listing files `ls -la`  (-a for all files) and you may find a hidden file/folder there.  Hidden folders have a '.' as first character.

Comment: added the exact debug messages, any suggestions?

Comment: or I was thinking, if I format this partition with ext4, will it be ok? I hope harddik not damaged :(, fdisk should do fine or any other tool better?

Comment: You cannot fix NTFS with Linux. But you can back it up, recover its contents, etc... then reformat.